# @RunWith(Cucumber.class) and @Autowired MockMvc

Tags: testing, spring-boot, cucumber, bdd

I try to use MockMvc within Cucumber tests but no spring dependencies are resolved.

I've create this class :

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = "pretty", features = "src/test/resources/features"})
@SpringBootTest
public class CucumberTest {

}
```

to run cucumber feature

And this class for steps :

```
@WebMvcTest(VersionController.class)
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
public class VersionControllerSteps {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private MvcResult result;

    @When("^the client calls /version$")
    public void the_client_issues_GET_version() throws Throwable {
        result = mvc.perform(get("/version")).andDo(print()).andReturn();
    }

    @Then("^the client receives status code of (\\d+)$")
    public void the_client_receives_status_code_of(int statusCode) throws Throwable {
        assertThat(result.getResponse().getStatus()).isEqualTo(statusCode);
    }

    @And("^the client receives server version (.+)$")
    public void the_client_receives_server_version_body(String version) throws Throwable {
        assertThat(result.getResponse().getContentAsString()).isEqualTo(version);
    }
}
```

but this throw exception :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.rest.VersionControllerSteps.the_client_issues_GET_version(VersionControllerSteps.java:30)
at ✽.When the client calls /version(version.feature:8)
```

Here is the .feature :

```
Feature: the version can be retrieved

  As a api user
  I want to know which api version is exposed
  In order to be a good api user

  Scenario: client makes call to GET /version
    When the client calls /version
    Then the client receives status code of 200
    And the client receives server version 1.0
```

How to configure my test to use cucumber and spring-boot ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which exact instruction is throwing the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 1):

Add @ContextConfiguration(classes = .class) Like below

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format = "pretty", features = "src/test/resources/features"})
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = <SpringBootApplication>.class)
public class CucumberTest {

}
```

This will work. I faced the same issue and got solved with this fix.

Comment: Yes. `@ContextConfiguration(classes = <You application main entry point>.class)` and mark the `mockMvc` as `@Autowired` helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your code listing and error log, it is not clear if it is a problem of cucumber+spring setup or just an application error.

The stack trace points at line 30, which is throwing the null pointer exception. From your code listing it looks it may be due to the `result.getResponse().getContentAsString()` instructions.

It may be worth checking if your controller is actually returning a body. For instance you may need to mark the returned value with the `@ResponseBody` annotation

```
   @RequestMapping(
     value = "/campaigns/new",
     method = RequestMethod.GET,
    )
    public @ResponseBody String vers() {
        return "1.0.1";
    }
```